# Laravel Migration append foreign key constraint incorrectly formed

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Trying to migrate a file but keep getting:
(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `permission_role` add constraint `permission_role_permission_id_foreign` foreign key (`permission_id`) references `permissions` (`id`) on delete cascade)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddForeignKeys extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::table('permission_role', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
        Schema::table('role_user', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        }); 
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating all this tables in just one migration?

Comment: @LucasPiazzi i can seperate it.

Answer (score 0):

First you should separate all your migrations. Make sure you create the `roles`,`users` and `permissions` tables first **(each one should have it's own migration)**. And then proceed creating the other ones.

> error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table permission_role add constraint permission_role_permission_id_foreign foreign key (permission_id) references permissions (id) on delete cascade)

This error is occuring because the `permissions` table have not been created yet, so you can't reference it in your foreign key.

Comment: Still getting the same error on permissions_role, i did what you suggested.

Comment: Can you edit the post with your current migrations now?

Comment: Also, make sure to checkout your file timestamps, you need to create the permissions table first.

Comment: I have seperated all the files out, they work, and are migrated.. the foreign key constraints though are still the error.

Comment: I took a look at your current migration and you forgot to define the FK, put this in your code:  `$table->unsignedInteger('permission_id');`

Comment: I am just adding foreign keys the permission id already exists